# Formatting DateTime issue with Ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, datetime-format

I have a string containing a time

```
text_t = 2:00 PM ET
```

I am trying to parse this into a DateTime object as such:

```
text_next = DateTime.strptime(text_t, '%I:%M %p %Z')
```

Yet when I print this it is giving me:

```
2013-07-02T14:00:00+00:00
```

Which according to this page:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_date_time.htm

should give me the hour in a 12 hour format. It does not though. %H does still give me a 24 hour clock as well. I need a 12 hour clock and must be able to get the AM-PM value as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the same format back using:

```
require 'date'

text_t = '2:00 PM ET'
text_next = DateTime.strptime(text_t, '%I:%M %p %Z')

text_next.strftime("%-l:%M %p #{text_t.split.last}")
#=> "2:00 PM ET"
```

Note that in `strftime`:

- `%-l` is used to get the hour without any padding.
- `text_t.split.last` is used to get the original abbrievated time zone since 'ET' is not a standard abbrievation.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'

text_t = '2:00 PM ET'
dt = DateTime.parse(text_t) 
# => #<DateTime: 2013-07-03T14:00:00+00:00 ((2456477j,50400s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
dt.strftime('%r') # => "02:00:00 PM"

text_t = '2:12:03 PM ET'
dt = DateTime.parse(text_t) 
# => #<DateTime: 2013-07-03T14:12:03+00:00 ((2456477j,51123s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
dt.strftime('%r') # => "02:12:03 PM"
```

Comment: that helps! but is that all I can do? I'm trying to format the string back to how the original text_t is formatted. I can definitely move on from here if I can't though. Just wondering..

Comment: You can call `strftime` with the format in your `strptime` call.

Comment: @tadman I didn't get your suggestion.Could you help me to understand the same ?

Comment: @Priti `dt.strftime('%l:%M %p %Z')` comes as close as you can get. `ET` is not a valid time-zone which is why your parsing is probably failing in the first place.

Comment: Yes I just ried this an it gives me +00:00. I will just concatenate it on. Many thanks